# Search multiple SOLR core's and return one result set

Tags: solr

We have several core's setup in SOLR and would like to search across these cores and return a single result set.

A bit more background:
We have a SOLR core that we index our internal blog engine.  We also have a SOLR core that we index our CMS system.  We would like to search across both of these cores but view a single result set.

I am aware of having related entities in a document, but we would like to keep the cores separate, for easy of maintenance, and redundancy.

We are using SolrSharp as a wrapper for searching SOLR.
Any advice or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: what client platform are you using?

Comment: We are using SolrSharp as a wrapper for SOLR.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since Solr 1.3, there's been decent multi-core search capabilities in Solr. Please read the [Distributed Search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch) article where it explains how to use the shards parameter to query across multiple cores and return results as one data set.

Comment: Does the DistributedSearch work though across multiple different cores?  Haven't tried it myself, but I wonder if it would be unhappy if core A has fields "name" and "title" and core B has fields "name" and "summary", and therefore they don't match?  Or would you get back name, summary, and title as appropriate?

Comment: Eric - 

My strategy is to employ a separate core with a merged schema that has a request handler implemented to search multiple shards. That way the client doesn't need to worry about providing the "shards" parameter.

Comment: So if I have Core0 with fields documentId,fieldA,fieldB and Core1 with fields documentId,fieldC,fieldD.  Then I create another core, lets say Core3 with fields documentId,fieldA,fieldB,fieldC,fieldD.  I will never be importing data into this core?  And then create a query handler, that includes the shard parameter.  So when I query Core3, it will never really contain indexed data, but because of the shard searching it will fetch the results from the other to cores, and "present" it on the 3rd core?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Rihan -

That's spot on what I'm recommending.

Comment: Could you provide an example config for this? Core3 with the query handler? Thanks!

Comment: @PureForm. I thought it will be useful for someone else. Use this to query data: http://localhost:8983/solr/global_search/browse/?q=test and this is the config: <requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
  <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
  <str name="rows">10</str>
  <str name="fl">NAME,SHORT_DESCRIPTION,score</str>
  <str name="shards">localhost:8983/solr/wiki/,localhost:8983/solr/information_log</str>
 </lst>
</requestHandler>

Comment: @BrianMansell Hi, I use url "localhost:8100/solr/core3/select?q=*%3A*", I did no get all the fields in core1 and core2. Please help me.

Comment: @BrianMansell Will it work in a scenario where core1 has fields a(Primary Key),b,c,q while core2 has fields p(Primary Key),q,r,b. In short for cores with different structure?

Comment: @RihanMeij So I created a third core with a request handler, however whenever I query it returns 2 different documents from 2 diff cores i.e it is just showing me both the results instead of performing the join and showing it as a single document. Could you help me with where am I going wrong?

Comment: Hi @happs I have moved away from the SOLR work, so I don't feel confidant in answering your question.  Sorry :(

Comment: Nowadays, maybe ElasticSearch can do this since it's document-based, not schema-based. You can store different-schema data in one core. (Note: I didn't delve into it, there seems  something called map, a kinda-like  schema, so I'm not sure firmly if it fits your need). Solr's schemaless is not "you-dont-need-schema", it's just "you-dont-have-schema-ready-first", but you still need to provide schema dynamically as what I read and understand so far.

Comment: @user1247412 The unique keys have to be the same field name, and unique across the different cores.

Answer (score 19):

There is no way to execute a single query across multiple cores. The **Distributed Search** mentioned in another answer is to do with shards which is splitting indexes across systems.

In fact, multiple cores are really for storing separate and different structures in each and querying multiple cores shouldn't make sense. As some have mentioned in previous comments, you can have an additional core which holds all your fields - though you may have to rename the fields in this new core so that similar named but differently typed fields can both be stored.

Answer (score 2):

Mathew's answer is exactly right. Shards and multi-cores are apples and oranges. You cannot have a unified single query across multiple cores. You have to perform individual queries per core (http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select?q=*:* ,http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/select?q=*:*). With shards however, (http://localhost:8983/solr/select?shards=localhost:8983/solr,localhost:8984/solr&q=*:*).

Answer (score 1):

Distributed search is the right answer.
I suggest to configure the distributed search directly in the handler.
You can configure localhost in the handler, although you may call solr externally.
Now you can call the search handler which will automatically search in all configured cores:

http://solrhost:8983/solr/core1?q=*:*

```
<requestHandler name="/multicore" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  ...
  <lst name="invariants">
    <str name="shards">localhost:8983/solr/core1,localhost:8983/solr/core2</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: If core1 and core2 have not-complete-same schemas, the result is unpredictable. After all, it's not reaonsable for schema-based Solr. In one word, there's no sugar answer for this tough question for Solr. Even for Elasticsearch, you still have to write codes to check what kind of data source type a document is and then extract corresponding fields(key=field name) from a specific document.