# Apache Solr - search multiple different cores simultaneously (cores with different document structure)

Tags: solr, solrj

I have an Apache Solr installation which runs 2 cores:

- the Machines core
- the Notifications core

Each core indexes a database table, so the content of the cores is completely different - by structure and actual content
Now i would like to run a search query on both of the cores and in the end to get a single result set from the 2 cores combines. For a trivial example if I would search for "2010" I would like my results to be relevant machine documents and notification documents, each from its own core, but combined as a result set, ordered by relevance.
Expected result set example:

- Machine #1
- Machine #2
- Notification #1
- Machine #3
- Notification #2
- Notification #3
- Machine #4

I will be interacting with Solr through SolrJ [Java connector].

Does anybody have any idea? Is what I am trying to do even possible ?

Thanks!

Comment: Checkout this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139030/search-multiple-solr-cores-and-return-one-result-set

Comment: I have read about Distributed Search, but doesn't it imply sharding? Meaning that each core has exactly the same document structure, only the data is different?

Comment: Distributed Search does imply sharing, but if you read the top answer to the question and the comments, it describes that you can have differing document structures, which is exactly what you are asking about.

Comment: This stackoverflow link may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139030/search-multiple-solr-cores-and-return-one-result-set

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is similar to a problem if stated as "I have an E-commerce portal where in I sell books, movies, music etc and multiple solr cores each searching one of them". Say a book name maybe a movie name too but how to solve the ranking/relevance conundrum when the results are to be retrieved from multiple absolutely different schemas?

For this Solr wont help you out with something out of box. You will have to build some wisdom of crowd or collective intelligence Algorithm to re-rank and do relevance stuff on top of what your every core returns.

Comment: So If I would like the behavior I described in the question, I would have to manually search each core, one at a time? [The 2 cores in my question were given just an example, I originally planned to have 10+ cores, one for each type of indexed database entity]

Comment: Absolutely not! Your search query will automatically will go to each core on its own however when the results are returned back (since they are from totally different schema's as you said) then you need a mechanism to re-rank them. What I mean is say you get from one core Mission Impossible movie and from other Books core Mission impossible book. Then you need to decide which one to place before the other. For this Solr can help you but you need to have some wisdom of crowd/collective intelligence algorithm to decide how to rank them.

Comment: Thank you, Yavar! Sorry if I seem too insistent with my questions, it is the first time I work with Solr. Although I would like to ask you 2 more things if this is ok: besides the crown/collective ranking algorithm is there any way to implement pagination to a search done on multiple cores, given the fact that I would have to re-renk the results ? And if, as you said, the results are returned from different cores with different schemas, in the result set there are documets with different structures as the example I have given in the original question? Thank you again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

> content of the cores is completely different - by structure and actual content

and

> I would like my results to be relevant machine documents and notification documents, each from its own core, but combined as a result set

implies that there are probably some common fields for the two cores and you want them to be displayed in the combined result set.

I suggest creating a new core with those common fields. The only drawback is that you would have to index machines and notifications to two cores.