# sharding between different solr server having different schema

Tags: solr, sharding

I have two different solr servers.
Both server has different schema.

Is it possible to shard these two solr server?

Or is there any other way to combine/merge results of two different solr servers?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer Yes,

I followed these instructions and I merged 10 (some have different schemas) cores into one request handler... [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139030/search-multiple-solr-cores-and-return-one-result-set)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the results from the two different servers.
Things you need to take care of

1. Define the different fields in both the schema so that no core throws exception for field missing
2. Define a single request handler with the fields you want to search on
3. For the common fields, If you want the score to be part, make sure the fields have the same field type.

Answer (score 0):

NuoDB database has a wide range of existing tools. One of this is the merger tool available with the Microsoft SQL Server database, that can move data between two data sources for which an ADO.NET driver is available. For more assistance, you can [click here](http://www.nuodb.com/techblog/2013/04/26/getting-started-migrate-a-database-from-sql-server-to-nuodb/) and get appropriate info.