# Solr search in multiple collections

Tags: php, solr, lucene

Iam working with Solr. My solr.xml file looks something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="true">
  <cores defaultCoreName="test1" host="${host:}" adminPath="/admin/cores" zkClientTimeout="${zkClientTimeout:15000}" hostPort="${jetty.port:8983}" hostContext="${hostContext:solr}">
    <core loadOnStartup="true" instanceDir="test1/" transient="false" name="test1" collection="test1"/>
    <core loadOnStartup="true" instanceDir="test2/" transient="false" name="test2" collection="test2"/>
  </cores>
</solr>
```

Now, i want to search in both collections. So i want the results that hit in collection1 or in collection2.

Must i send two requests or is solr able to handle one request against 2 (or more) collections.

I could do something like this:

```
http://***.***.***.***:8080/solr/test1/select?q=field%3Dtest&wt=xml&indent=true
http://***.***.***.***:8080/solr/test2/select?q=field%3Dtest&wt=xml&indent=true
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search multiple SOLR core's and return one result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139030/search-multiple-solr-cores-and-return-one-result-set)

Answer (score 1):

you can check for Solr [distributed search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch), which will allow you to search across Collections.

However, be sure you are maintaining common fields in both the cores so that the query finds them and returns them.
Also, distributed search also has some [limitations](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch#Distributed_Searching_Limitations).

Else, you need to query differently and consolidate the results.

Comment: I will take a look at it. But the collections are differrent. In collection1 are products of one group and in collection2 product from another group. So i think i have to query differently.